# Error in the R.java file when trying to compile

Tags: android

I allways get the message "Syntax error on token "int", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" for the following line in the R.java file:

```
public static final class drawable {         
public static final int =0x7f0200c5;
```

Comment: Because you didn't put a variable name there.

Comment: Please provide complete code sample and format your post.

Comment: You should **never** mess with the R.java file! It's generated by the system - leave it **as is**. Delete it and rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your xml for errors, plus never edit or open your R.java file it says that clearly on top of the file. Maybe something is missing in resources

Answer (score 0):

i think you  are using a image inside drawable which name is not in proper format according to android like use abc_efg.png. dnt use special characters in nomenclature.